# R lubridate: Why do I get a "unknown timezone" error?

Tags: r, lubridate

Why is it I get an "unknown timezone" error when I am trying to use the `mdy` function?

```
> library(lubridate)

Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    date

> mdy('15-01-2018')
Error in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : 
  (converted from warning) unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2017c.1.0/zoneinfo/Asia/Hong_Kong'
```

Comment: Are you on OS X High Sierra?

Comment: How come `m` be `15`? try `dmy`

Comment: If you are on High Sierra you can solve this by updating R to its newest version.

Comment: Also `mdy('15-01-2018')` should  be `mdy('01-15-2018')`

Comment: @MattGibson Thanks for your tip, which helped me to to figure it out.

Comment: @Prem Thanks for your tip, which helped me to to figure it out.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your tip, which helped me to to figure it out.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess Thanks for your tip, which helped me to to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [Matt Gibson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300836/matt-gibson) and [Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland),
the error has to do with running an older version of R.

I had installed R version 3.4.1 around August 2017,
when my computer was running macOS 10.12 Sierra.
Around November 2017, I had updated macOS to 10.13 High Sierra.
After I installed R version 3.4.3,
the `unknown timezone` error no longer appeared.

```
> library(lubridate)

Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    date

> mdy('15-01-2018')
[1] NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Of course, the format fails to parse,
because as [Prem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8240561/prem)
and [InfiniteFlashChess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5874001/infiniteflashchess) mentioned,
I had mixed up the month and date in the `mdy` function.

```
> mdy('01-15-2018')
[1] "2018-01-15"
```